# Error al editar un contacto con su categoria correspondiente, Undefined array key en la variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

estoy intentando editar un contacto con su categoría especifica pero esta me da error de Undefined array key, y está declarada pero algo debo de estar haciendo mal.
La idea es que al editar dicho contacto salga su correspondiente categoría pero esta sale en blanco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***El error del formulario***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias de antemano pego el código.

***Tabla***

```
<?php 
    include '../../config/conexion.php';
    $query_contactos = $bd->query("SELECT contactos.id_contactos AS id_contactos, contactos.nombre AS nombre,contactos.apellido_1 
    as apellido_1,contactos.apellido_2 as apellido_2,contactos.telefono as telefono,
    contactos.email as email,categorias.nombre as categoria
    FROM t_contactos AS contactos
    INNER JOIN t_categorias AS categorias ON contactos.id_categoria = categorias.id_categoria");
    $t_contactos = $query_contactos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //print_r($t_contactos);
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css">
        <title>Lista de Contactos</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3 id="mostrar">Lista de Contactos</h3>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Apellido 1</td>
                <td>Apellido 2</td>
                <td>Teléfono</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Categoria</td>
                <td>Accion 1</td>
                <td>Accion 2</td>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($t_contactos as $fila_C) {  ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->id_contactos; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->nombre; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->apellido_1; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->apellido_2; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->telefono; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->email;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila_C->categoria;?></td>
                <td><a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $fila_C->id_contactos; ?>id_categoria=<?php echo $fila_C->categoria; ?>">Editar</a></td>
                <td><a href="../procesos/tabla_contactos/eliminarProceso.php?id=<?php echo $fila_C->id_contactos; ?>">Eliminar</a></td>
                
            <?php } ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***Formulario que recoge los datos***

```
<?php 
    include '../../config/Conexion.php';
    
    //print_r($_GET);
    
    if(!isset($_GET['id']) && !isset($_GET['id_categoria'])){
        header('Location: ../vista_de_contactos/listar_contactos.php');
    }

    $id_contactos = $_GET['id'];
    $id_categoria = $_GET['id_categoria'];

    try {
        $query_contactos = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_contactos WHERE id_contactos = ? ORDER BY id_contactos;");
        $query_contactos->execute([$id_contactos]);
        $t_contactos = $query_contactos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        //print_r($t_contacto);
    } catch (PDOException $eContacto) {
        echo "Error en la sentencia <br>".$eContacto->getMessage();
    }

    try {
        $query_categorias = $bd->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_categorias WHERE id_categoria = ?  ORDER BY id_categoria;");
        $query_categorias->execute([$id_categoria]);
        $t_categorias = $query_categorias->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
        /*$query_categorias->execute();
        $t_categorias = $query_categorias->fetchAll();*/
    } catch (PDOException $eCategorias) {
        echo "Error en la sentencia <br>".$eCategorias->getMessage();
    }   
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../style.css">
    <title>Editar Contactos</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3 class="insertar">Editar Contactos</h3>
        <form method="POST" action="../procesos/tabla_contactos/editarProceso.php">
        Categorias
        <select name="id_categoria">
            <?php foreach($t_categorias as $fila_C) : 
                echo '<option value="'.$fila_C['id_categoria'].'">'.$fila_C['nombre'].'</option>';
            endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->nombre;?>">

            <label for="apellido_p">apellido 1</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido_1" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->apellido_1;?>">

            <label for="apellido_m">Apellido 2</label>
            <input type="text" name="apellido_2" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->apellido_2;?>">

            <label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
            <input type="text" name="telefono" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->telefono;?>">

            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->email;?>">


            <input type="hidden" name="oculto">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->id_contactos;?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="id_categoria" value="<?php echo $t_contactos->categoria;?>">
            
            <input type="submit" value="Actualizar Contacto">
        </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Aquí el proceso que realiza el update, perdón que ayer se me olvidó

```
<?php 
     include '../../../config/Conexion.php';
    // print_r($_POST);
    if(!isset($_POST['oculto'])){
        header('Location: ../../vista_de_contactos/listar_contactos.php');
    }
    
    try {
        $id_contactos = $_POST['id'];
        $id_categoria = $_POST['id_categoria'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido_1 = $_POST['apellido_1'];
        $apellido_2 = $_POST['apellido_2'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $categoria = $_POST['nombre'];

        $query_actualizar = $bd->prepare("UPDATE t_contactos SET id_categoria = ?,nombre = ?,apellido_1 = ?,apellido_2 = ?,telefono = ?,email = ? 
        WHERE id_contactos = ?;");
        $resultado = $query_actualizar->execute([$id_categoria,$nombre,$apellido_1,$apellido_2,$telefono,$email,$id_contactos]);
        //print_r($query_actualizar);    

        if($resultado === true){
            header('Location: ../../vista_de_contactos/listar_contactos.php');
        }
    } catch (PDOException $eMostrarUP) {
        echo "Error al ejecutar la sentencia actualizar ".$eMostrarUP->getMessage();

    }

?>
```

Comment: y donde esta `UPDATE tabla SET...`?

Comment: Hola Sebastian la acabo de poner, perdona que ayer con las prisas se me olvidó. Un saludo.

Comment: No veo que estés seleccionando ningún `option` en el `select` cuyo name es `id_categoria` (primer elemento en la imagen). Si no seleccionas nada ahí, no se enviará ningún valor asociado cuando envíes el formulario. Otra cosa: ¿por qué si el método del formulario es POST luego usas `$_GET` para recogerlos. Aunque esto funciona **a veces**, debes usar siempre la superglobal del método del formulario, por coherencia y porque a veces si no usas la superglobal propia el código no funcionará. Para depurar lo que estás enviando pon un `var_dump($_POST);` donde se recogen los datos.

Comment: el caso esta en que cuando pongo la super global $_POST me manda al index y no selecciona nada

Comment: ¿Pusiste el `var_dump($_POST);` como te sugerí? ¿Qué muestra?